# How can my method return a value computed within a lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda, vert.x

Here's a simplified version of what my code looks like:

```
public void pairing() {
    WebClient web = WebClient.create(vertx);
    String url = "/request";
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    web
        .post(6660, "localhost", url)
        .sendJsonObject(obj, response -> {
            JsonObject pairing = response.result().body().toJsonObject(); // what I want to return
        }
}
```

This makes a POST request to localhost:6660/request, and I create a new JsonObject called pairing that stores the response to that request. I could process pairing inside of the lambda expression for the request, but ideally, I would be able to return the JsonObject to the method that calls pairing() and process it from there.

I tried this:

```
public JsonObject pairing() {
    JsonObject pairing = new JsonObject();
    WebClient web = WebClient.create(vertx);
    String url = "/request";
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    web
        .post(6660, "localhost", url)
        .sendJsonObject(obj, response -> {
            pairing = response.result().body().toJsonObject();
        }
    return pairing;
}
```

But it doesn't work because I get the "pairing must be final or effectively final" error. Is there some way I can return "pairing" from this method so that I can access it elsewhere in my program? Or am I possibly approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Does the "sendJsonObject()" method have a return type?

Comment: Nope, it's void. Here's a link to [the API](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/HttpRequest.html) which I meant to include in my post.

Comment: Yeah, it's meant to be an asynchronous client interface so you can't do it like that. The lambda is where you're supposed to handle the response because it's possible that at the moment your code reaches the "return" statement the call still hasn't received a response.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. It would be nice if there were some way around it, but it's not the end of the world if I have to do all my processing inside the lambda. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to do it inside the lambda, take the value and throw it into a separate method where the flow continues - think of it as just a callback method for once the response has been received. You can't handle asynchronous code in a synchronous way.

Comment: Yup, I think that'll be the plan :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use futures:

```
public Future<JsonObject> pairing() {
        Future<JsonObject> future = Future.future();
    WebClient web = WebClient.create(vertx);
    String url = "/request";
    JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
    web
        .post(6660, "localhost", url)
        .sendJsonObject(obj, response -> {
            future.complete(response.result().body().toJsonObject());
        }
    return future;
}
```

Now to call this function:

```
pairing().setHandler(r -> {
    r.result // This is your JSON object
});
```

`WebClient` will execute asynchronously. What you are trying is synchronous, which is not possible using WebClient, and also synchronous call will be a blocking call in vert.x. Thats also the golden rule, do not block the event loop.

Comment: I didn't realize that future.complete() could be used that way! This works. Thanks!